# Apache2 needing restart every night

Tags: server, apache2, php, svn, owncloud-server

I would need help to pinpoint an issue which is needing me to restart the apache2 service every night approx always at the same time.

Virtualized Ubuntu Server 18.10 which is running the afore mentioned apache2 webserver, hosting an svn installation and an ownCloud installation

Background:
The whole used to work just fine without ever needing my attention, but now, after some upgrades at both some modules and php, every morning I find zombied apache2 processes and an unresponsive server. A simple `sudo service apache2 restart` is fixing it for good until next morning.

I'd need help to find the issue looking in the right logs and config files, please.
Feel free to ask me any information about my system and I will add the details as EDITS

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I have the same issue. Clean install, and apache apparently is running (`systemctl status apache2` returns active), but for some reason, the server is inaccessible from the web. A quick apache restart and it's good to go again.

Comment: Didn't have time to investigate, but I'm under the impression it could be related to ownCloud (mobile) clients making the server to crash: after uninstalling these clients, the issue went away. When I have more time I'll try to bring them back on and to go through the logs...

Comment: Thanks. I don't have ownCloud, just a pretty straight forward LAMP stack, but for some reason the server is inaccessible every morning when I try to connect.